# Logstash grok & regex filter

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, elk

Wanting a filter that extracts given information from log messages.

Currently using, although it's very specific to one format/log layout

```
filter {
  if "ONT" in [message] {
   grok{
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{WORD:Alarm_Severity} %{DATA:Message} %{QS:ONT_ID} %{DATA:Time} %{QS:ONT_Message}" }
   }
 }
```

Log Files are:

```
Dec 16 15:01:13 172.20.x.xx NPF_OLT_LAB05: clear Alarm for card 1/1 at 2019/12/16 15:01:13.39: "Backup files exist"
Dec 16 15:01:13 172.20.x.xx NPF_OLT_LAB05: service "403
 for ONT: "10002" - ONT needs restart at 2019/12/16 15:01:13.39 ONT message: "Backup files exist"
```

Wanting layout to give me these parameters
Time:15:01:13

Host: NPF_OLT_LAB05

Alarm Severity: clear

ONT ID: 10002

Source IP: 172.20.x.xx

ONT Message: "Backup files exist"

Message: clear Alarm for card 1/1

Service ID: 403

Answer (score 1):

I guess these are two different logs, you need to have two different grok pattern as below,

Dec 16 15:01:13 172.20.12.12 NPF_OLT_LAB05: clear Alarm for card 1/1 at 2019/12/16 15:01:13.39: "Backup files exist"

Grok pattern

```
(?<Date>%{MONTH} +%{MONTHDAY}) %{TIME:Time} %{IPV4:SourceIP} %{NOTSPACE:HOST}\:\s(%{WORD:Severity} %{GREEDYDATA:Message})\s(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}\/%{MONTHNUM}\/%{MONTHDAY}\s%{TIME})\S\s\S%{GREEDYDATA:ONTMessage}\"
```

Dec 16 15:01:13 172.20.x.xx NPF_OLT_LAB05: service "403 for ONT: "10002" - ONT needs restart at 2019/12/16 15:01:13.39 ONT message: "Backup files exist"

Grok pattern

```
(?<Date>%{MONTH} +%{MONTHDAY}) %{TIME:Time} %{IPV4:SourceIP} %{NOTSPACE:HOST}\S\s%{WORD:Severity}\s\S%{BASE10NUM:ServiceID} %{NOTSPACE}\s(?:ONT: \S%{BASE10NUM:ONT_ID}\S) %{NOTSPACE} %{GREEDYDATA:Message}\s(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}\/%{MONTHNUM}\/%{MONTHDAY}\s%{TIME}) (?:ONT message\: \S(?<ONT Message:>%{GREEDYDATA}\S))
```

Below Conf

```
 filter {
      if "ONT" in [message] {
       grok{
          match => { "message" => [ "(?<Date>%{MONTH} +%{MONTHDAY}) %{TIME:Time} %{IPV4:SourceIP} %{NOTSPACE:HOST}\:\s(%{WORD:Severity} %{GREEDYDATA:Message})\s(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}\/%{MONTHNUM}\/%{MONTHDAY}\s%{TIME})\S\s\S%{GREEDYDATA:ONTMessage}\"" , 
                                  "(?<Date>%{MONTH} +%{MONTHDAY}) %{TIME:Time} %{IPV4:SourceIP} %{NOTSPACE:HOST}\S\s%{WORD:Severity}\s\S%{BASE10NUM:ServiceID} %{NOTSPACE}\s(?:ONT: \S%{BASE10NUM:ONT_ID}\S) %{NOTSPACE} %{GREEDYDATA:Message}\s(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}\/%{MONTHNUM}\/%{MONTHDAY}\s%{TIME}) (?:ONT message\: \S(?<ONT Message:>%{GREEDYDATA}\S))" ]
          }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Instead of doing one long pattern, it might be a better idea to use two different patterns in the same grok filter. Or if there's an easy way to distinguish the two formats, something like this could work: `if ... { grok { match => pattern1} } else { grok { match => pattern2 } }`

Comment: the above grok filter has two different patterns sepreated by comma.
grok { match => { "message" => "pattern1" , "pattern2" }}

Comment: I missed that. In that case I usually put a line break after the comma so that it's visible there's two patterns.

Comment: Also when using more than one pattern, you need to put them between brackets: `"message" => [ "pattern1" , "pattern2"] `. [See the second example in the doc there.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-match)

Comment: Would it be possible to use regex to pick out individual words ie "ONT ID": *----*
As I am going to be using different types of log messages in logstash that will collect syslog information from various sources on my network.